# How to open file without extension

Tags: java, file-io, desktop-application

I would like to try open file without extension. When I try to open file without extension, then system show me "Open with" form. But when I am trying to open that file in side my application using method:

```
    private static void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            File file = new File(fileName);
            desktop.open(file);
        } else {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c start %s", fileName));
        }
    }
```

system don't show this form.
How to solve this?

Comment: Hi,

Does it throws an Exception?

Comment: Why not add an extension to the file. It will be clearer for your users as to what the file is for.

Comment: Yes. Method throws exception: java.io.IOException. Error message: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I think this link could be helpful: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#isSupported(java.awt.Desktop.Action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop.open() launches the application associated with the extension of the file.

Comment: Perhaps the best question for the OP would be, what does the file with no extension open in when you double click it?  A quick test here on Win 7 with a `.png` changed to remove the extension, produces an `Open with` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
   desktop.open(file);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c start %s", file));
}
```