# find picture in folder withot extension

Tags: java

how can I get all files in folder only by name **without** extension file?
for example I have picture name "pic1" and I don't know  extension it can be "gif","jpeg","png"
I tried that but it's also looking for extension:

```
   File dir = new File("...");
    String[] files = dir.list(new NameFileFilter("pic1"));
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(files[i]);
    }
```

thank,

Comment: Have you looked into similar threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741170/how-to-find-file-without-extension

Comment: You can check this link out :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310877/how-to-open-file-without-extension

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] files = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        //return name.startsWith("pic1.");
        return name.matches("(?i)pic1\\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)");
    }
});
```

Java 8:

```
String[] files = dir.list((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("pic1."));
```

Answer (score 0):

List the files without providing a filter, then loop on the list: if fileNameString.startsWith("pic1") then do your logic.

To do this more correctly, use FilenameUtils.removeExtension() from Apache Commons IO (on the file name).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the Apache library, try:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("pic1.*");
String[] files = dir.list(fileFilter);
```